# How to increase root directory Size by adding from /dev/sda3

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I bought a **VDS** server which has `100GB SSD and Ubuntu 18.04` is running in it. After that I installed `docker and nginx`. But after one day my docker containers are not running and nginx also returning `502 Bad Gateway` response because nginx error log shows `No space left on device` error. Then I checked `df -H` command. It it like below:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              313M   37M  276M  12% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  4.2G  4.2G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          1.1G  156M  798M  17% /boot
tmpfs                              313M     0  313M   0% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop1                         105M  105M     0 100% /snap/core/11316
/dev/loop2                         2.1M  2.1M     0 100% /snap/fast/4
/dev/loop3                         105M  105M     0 100% /snap/core/11420
```

`lsblk` result:

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1                       7:1    0 99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11316
loop2                       7:2    0    2M  1 loop /snap/fast/4
loop3                       7:3    0 99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11420
sda                         8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   99G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    4G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

`fdisk -l` result:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FSE23SFG-FR21-4A89-A826-DFASDASD

Device       Start       End   Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   2101247   2097152   1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 209713151 207611904  99G Linux filesystem
```

What should I to do to make `/` root directory more bigger. So that my other progams run correctly like `docker and nginx`. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You will need to enlarge the LV to use more space from the VG--which is difficult to do on a running/live system. Alternatively, you can create additional/separate LV's for the /home, /usr, /var, and other standard LFS directories (and copy the files/subdirs within them) in to their own LV, so they are not using space in the root LV, then remount/reboot. Both methods are long and detailed, with many guides on the web you can follow, hence why I am posing a comment not an answer.

Comment: Can you give some links for detailed information on how to do that?

Comment: [Google: linux lvm enlarge root lv](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+lvm+enlarge+root+lv) and [Google: linux lvm move /home /usr /var to their own lv](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+lvm+move+%2Fhome+%2Fusr+%2Fvar+to+their+own+lv)

Comment: Thank you for your help!